# finding limit: result division by null

Tags: limits

I've got a question concerning this task:
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -{\frac{1}2}^+}{\frac{e^{2x-1}-1}{cos(\pi x)}}$$ 
So the limit value given in the solution is $-\infty$.

I am a bit confused about limit values and division by null in that context; So I know that in general $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\frac{1}2}{\frac{1}{cos(\pi x)}}$ doesn't exist since the limit value is different for $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow {-\frac{1}2}^-}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow {-\frac{1}2}^+}$.
In my case ,though, it is possible because I'm only interested in $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -{\frac{1}2}^+}{cos(\pi x)}=0^+$ and therefore, with $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -{\frac{1}2}^+}{e^{2x-1}-1}={e^{-2}-1}^+$ that gives me $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -{\frac{1}2}^+}{\frac{e^{2x-1}-1}{cos(\pi x)}}=\frac{{e^{-2}-1}^+}{0^+}$$ which is in that case $-\infty$, since the numerator is $<0$, right?
So could I say that I can - in the context of limit values - divide by null if I'm only interested in the limit value from one side?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have arrived at the limit correctly; what you can say is that you have a positive infinitesimal (number approaching zero from the positive side) in the denominator and a negative constant in the numerator, which has limit $-\infty$.  You can also first note that $\lim_{x\to\frac 12} e^{2x-1}-1=e^{-2}-1$ which is constant, then pull that constant out and deal with the remaining $\frac 1{\cos(\pi x)}$.

Comment: alright thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

It is not $e^{-2}$ but $e^0$. You have to use L'Hopital rule to get
$$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -{\frac{1}2}^+}{\frac{e^{2x-1}-1}{\cos(\pi x)}}=
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -{\frac{1}2}^+}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{2x-1}-1\right)}{\frac{d}{dx} \cos(\pi x)}=
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -{\frac{1}2}^+}\frac{2 e^{2x-1}}{ -\pi \sin(\pi x)}=
-\frac{2}{\pi}
$$

Comment: that is incorrect. It would be e^0 if x->1/2 since e^(2*0,5-1)-1=0. In that case I could use L'Hospital since the numerator and the denominator have the limit value 0, or am I wrong?